# Latest time for various parts of korbanot

Tags: tefilla, zemanim, korbanos-ketores-prayers

During the week, I often say korbanot after davening, generally in the car driving to work (there's not enough time in the car on the way to shul, and this way I have an uninterrupted block of time).  If I end up leaving late, what are the latest times to say the various parts?  As a related question, if I forget to say it on the way there, which parts can I still say on the way home when I say korbanot shel bein haarbayim?

My best guesses are:

- Kiyor - makes sense to say before saying any other part, whenever it is
- Terumat hadeshen - in the morning, but I don't have any more specific feeling
- Tamid - sof zman tefilla
- Ketoret - We say the one after davening on Rosh Hashana even if davening ends in the afternoon, so I would guess that it would make sense to say even in the afternoon.
- Abayei hava mesader - all day?
- Ana vechoach - any time, connected to ketoret
- Ribon Kol Haolamim - I assume this is connected to Abayei hava mesader, since it's not said at Mincha
- Musafim - all day, but if it's in the afternoon, should it be said before the tamid (like the actual korban) or after (like davening mincha and musaf)?
- Eizehu mekoman and Rabbi Yishmael - all day

If I forget to say it in the morning, my guess would be kiyor, ketoret (for Shacharit), musafim when relevant, tamid, ketoret again, then Abayei hava mesader and continue as in Shacharit.

Is there a source who discusses this?  Of course most of it is Torah and you can say it whenever you want, but I'm asking when it makes sense to say it more than it makes sense to say other pesukim, mishnayot, and gemaras.

Comment: Sof Zman Musaf is 7 hours into the day. (OC 287)

Comment: Some say the Lechem HaPanim on Shabbat. Consider also the placement of the verses related to the Korban Pesach, the Korban HaOmer and the Shtei HaLechem which aren't accounted for in regular prayers.